# XML If's and Whens?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to create an XML/XSLT document which takes advantage of IF's and WHEN's. I'm familiar these statements in PHP (albeit if/else) however unfamiliar with XML/XSLT.

For example I have a product, the product has the possibility of 2 names:
1) Laminated Business Cards
2) Business Cards

If it's option 1, then I need to get the value of a custom option for that order and echo it out like so:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="custom_options/option[name='Lamination Options (Your printing looks great     unlaminated, if you wish you can add gloss or matt lamination below)']/value='Matt Lamination (Both sides)'">
<Extrinsic name="Laminating?">Matt Lam DS SRA3</Extrinsic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="custom_options/option[name='Lamination Options (Your printing looks great unlaminated, if you wish you can add gloss or matt lamination below)']/value='Gloss Lamination  (Both sides)'">
<Extrinsic name="Laminating?">Gloss Lam DS SRA3</Extrinsic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

So I need to check the name of the product if it contains the word laminating then run another if statement, if not run a different if statement, so if it was PHP it would look like this:

```
<?php $product = "Laminated Business Cards";
if(strpos($product,'Laminated')){
    if(value of custom option == 'Matt Laminated'){
        echo "Matt Lam";
    } elseif(value of custom option == 'Gloss Laminated'){
        echo "Gloss Lam";
    } else echo "No Lamination";
} elseif(value of custom option == 'Matt Laminated +2days'){
        echo "Matt Lam";
    } elseif(value of custom option == 'Gloss Laminated +2days'){
        echo "Gloss Lam";
    } else 
echo "No Lamination";
```

?>

So I need to reproduce that in XSLT/XML. I know it's a bit messy but I'm working within the contraints of a poorly designed system with little option other than to take this route.

Cheers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Magento - it's strictly an XML/XSLT question.

Comment: I added Magento simply because I had mention of "Custom Options" in there and didn't want to confuse people.

Comment: Adding Magento to *prevent* confusion? :-D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your question is. You've got some XSLT code and some PHP code and they seem rather different; I'm not sure why. It doesn't help that we can't see your source document. Your XSLT code shows that you've mastered the basics of xsl:choose; it can of course be nested to include one xsl:choose inside the xsl:when of another xsl:choose. So where exactly is your problem?

The one thing I would add is that experienced XSLT users often avoid writing complex xsl:choose instructions and break the logic up into template rules instead. So you might see a series of template rules like this:

```
<xsl:template match="options[@name='Laminated' and @value='Matt Laminated']">
  <xsl:text>Matt Lam</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```